# there is an object that I want to set Inactive when it shows. but the problem is, it just runs one time. what I want is to loop so I can reuse it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the problem is I dont know how to loop the Script and I hope someone could help me

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Disabletimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject targetObject;
    public float Wait_time = 3f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait_to_disable());
    }

    IEnumerator Wait_to_disable()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Wait_time);
        targetObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

what I expect the Script to do is that, I want the object disabled within a time limit whenever that object is enabled, and also want it to loop so that when that object shows again it will do that task again.

Comment: Please ask more specific and give more context. What do you mean with Script in this context? How is this code part called (from where)? What have you already tried for the loop?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well.  This disables an object after some time. So what is the actual issue?

Comment: By "Looping" he means that he wants it to repeat this behavior during runtime, so just changing the StartCoroutine from Start to OnEnable should do the trick

Comment: The OnEnable really did the work thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code from Start to OnEnable, this will make it happen every time that it is enabled